# View Notebook in Sagemaker Studio without automatically starting a kernel or instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

Currently, when you double-click on a notebook in Sagemaker that you've ran before, the notebook will open with your previous kernel and rent an instance

Sometimes, I just want to view the notebook and not run a notebook kernel session

How can I disable this automatic behaviour, and only pick a kernel when I explicitly pick from the dropdown?

I've tried looking for documentation but cannot find this

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior on Studio, and it picks up the instance type from the notebook's metadata. There is LCC script you can use to avoid this behaviour - https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-lifecycle-config-examples/pull/26